# How to use a dynamic variable in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, db2

I am creating an upate trigger. I have a situation where I need to test a condition on a table column, without actually knowing what the exact column name is. The trigger is generic and can  applied to any table, with varying columns.

Pseudo-code:

```
// define a cursor that loops through all columns in "MyTable"
Define cursor C1 for (select COLS from SYSCAT.TABLES where TABS="MyTable")
FOR
// take the next column from the cursor
@temp_var = C1.COLS
// DELETED and INSERTED are tables that also contain the same columns as "MyTable" table.
if(DELETED.@temp_var <> INSERTED.@temp_var)
THEN
...
```

The above statement `if(DELETED.@temp_var <> ...` does of course not work, but maybe you can see what I am trying to do? So I would want it to be during runtime e.g. `if(DELETED.MyColumn <>... where "MyColumn"`is a column in`"MyTable"`and also in`INSERTED`and`DELETED columns`. Note that because this method should be generic, I do not know beforehand what columns the table has (depends on the specific table in use).

Any ideas on how to build the if-statement dynamically like that?

Comment: If you don't know what the column name is, how do you expect the trigger to know? Triggers don't accept variables. You may be able to use CONTEXT_INFO but yuck, yuck, yuck.

Comment: thanks for your reply Aaron! Well, I can't specify the column names because they will be different for different column, but the Cursor does know. The cursor contains in "COLS" all the table column names. That is why I am trying to use it to retrieve the table columns.

Comment: I see that you are looping through all the columns in the table, but that still doesn't explain how your cursor is going to know which one is the one.

Comment: The only thing that matters is that this function loops through all the columns in the table (and it does). It does not matter in what order the columns are iterated, or what column it is currently at. The important part is that when the "if" statement is executed, the current column can be compared between tables DELETED and INSERTED.

Comment: And just to clarify, the @temp_var variable gets the column name that the cursor currently points to.

Comment: Ok, so you need to compare *every* column, not just one column based on a single value. Next question: what do you expect to happen if your trigger fires in response to a multi-row operation? Right now you seem to care about only one row. I realize it is tagged for multiple platforms (and I hope you don't expect a single answer for all those platforms), but in SQL Server at least, there may be some misunderstanding about triggers. They fire once per operation, not once per row.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent [Columns_Updated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: Aaron: I am woring with DB2 which has a functionality for making the trigger fire upon change of every row, which I have chosen to do. It can also work on per operation, but I chose not to.

Comment: HABO: I am working with DB2 which unfortunately does not have this operation (yet). But yes, this is basically what I am trying to do. I am hoping there would be some generic solution for this, not DB2 specific. Maybe one could try with inline SQL, I don't know...

Comment: Why are you attempting to do this dynamically?  I'm not completely sure that triggers are able to tell which table they're applied to (other than a 'current' type reference); triggers are _usually_ customized per-table.  Do all instances of the `MyTable` family have the same set of columns - if so, does it _have_ to be dynamic?  What is the larger problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: X-Zero: I will apply the trigger to hundreds of tables and do not want to customize the trigger separately. You can get (from a system table) the trigger name and the table it is created in. However, I do not need to use that functionality because the stored procedure creating the trigger passes down the table name to the trigger.

Comment: Z-Zero: MyTable is only an example. In the next trigger the table name could be "MyTable2" with a different set of columns. Therefore the columns are not known at write-time, but the C1 Cursor gets this information at run-time. That is why I am trying to pass the variable in the IF-statement.

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 SQL you cannot refer to columns dynamically.  So, you won't be able to do that using only SQL.  You could possibly call an external procedure written in another language from within the trigger.  Or, you could rethink your overall design for what you are trying to do.  I don't see any other options.